# DiscordJs - Member undefined when remove reaction first

Tags: javascript, discord.js

im trying to make a basic bot add/remove role when add/remove reaction from a post on discord.

The code works if i add the role first and then remove it, but lets say i already have the role and restart the script. When i remove the reaction the script gives me the error saying:
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')"

```
client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
if (reaction.partial) {
    try {
        await reaction.fetch();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message:', error);
        return;
    }
}

if (reaction.message.id != pinnedMsg) {
    return;
}
var role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "ROLENAME");
const guild = reaction.message.guild;

const member = await guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);

member.roles.remove(role); }); //var member is undefined here
```

Comment: Fetch the member if he isn't cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch members with [`<Guild>.members.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) because they are not cached. Don't forget to use `await` when needed, to find in cache it's not necessary.

Example for your case:

```
await guild.members.fetch();
const member = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
```

Comment: solved the problem. Thank you!